# Wifi Issues in HP Probook 450 G8

Tags: 20.04, wireless, hp, 21.04, iwlwifi

We have many HP Laptops with ubuntu, but in recent updates of Ubuntu we are facing issues with Wi-Fi, wifi suddenly gone after installing updates, can anyone help me on this issue?

---

Output of @jeremy31 Requirement:

ii linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic 5.13.0-28.31 amd64 Linux Kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64bit x86 SMP

Comment: Check result from terminal for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Here is the output of above command:

ii     linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic         5.13.0-28.31            amd64              Linux Kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64bit x86 SMP

Comment: Add the info to the question not as a comment.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.